# DataTables how to get each table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have multiple tables that is using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

```
/* Data Table Initialization */
var $materialDataTable = $('.materialTable').dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ "sClass": "text-center", "aTargets": [ 0,9 ] },
             { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 9 ] }]
});
```

Let us say the number of table that has `.materialTable` class is 2.

I want to add a row in a specific table.

I tried this:

```
$materialDataTable[0].fnAddData( [ 
    '1',
    '<a href="#" class="materialItem" data-type="text">N/A</a>',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    '0',
    '0',
    '0',
    '0',
    '<input type="checkbox" class="deleteMaterialCheckBox">' ]);
```

But this doesn't work. It gives me this error `Object #<HTMLTableElement> has no method 'fnAddData'`

To make it short **I want to add a row to a specific table when a button is clicked** but I don't know how can I select a specific table from the initialization above.

Comment: Have you tried `$($materialDataTable[0]).fnAddData(...)` ?

Comment: @SirDerpington Yes it gives `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fnAddData' `

Comment: Sorry in my example I missed the `.dataTable()`...but I guess `$($materialDataTable[0]).dataTable().fnAddData(...)` won't work either, or?

Comment: now that works. Can you post the answer so I can accept it with the details why it doesn't work?

Comment: I hope my answer explains your issue ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your debugger says `Object #<HTMLTableElement> has no method 'fnAddData'`.
This is because `<HTMLTableElement>` just holds the raw HTML of your object. It's not a jQuery Object and therefore has no methods at all.

With the `$(...)` wrapped around it becomes a jQuery Object and you can access all the methods and properties available.

Try `console.log($materialDataTable[0])` and `console.log($($materialDataTable[0])` to see the differences in your DevTool of choice.

As mentioned in the comments the solution to your problem is:

```
$($materialDataTable[0]).dataTable().fnAddData(...)
```

**EDIT**

See this simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wr8JZ/1/). Sometimes I'm bad at explaining but this examples shows what your issue is/was.